# Como fazer o jogador se movimentar em "slide" na unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Sou nova na unity e estou fazendo o tutorial [RogueLike 2D](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/s/2d-roguelike-tutorial). Por padrão o jogador vai se mover, ***teoricamente***, utilizando uma dessas coordenadas por turno `y+1, x+1, y-1, x-1`, ou seja apenas um bloco por vez. 
E quero saber como posso fazer o jogador se movimentar livremente até colidir contra uma parede ou outro colisor qualquer da cena.

Como o jogo [2048](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVgvnuHipyA), onde os quadrados avançam em linha reta e só param quando colidem na parede ou em outras peças.

Abaixo está a parte do código que declara o movimento. Quais alterações devo fazer para deixar o movimento conforme citei acima?

```
//Co-routine for moving units from one space to next, takes a parameter end to specify where to move to.
protected IEnumerator SmoothMovement (Vector3 end)
{
    //Calculate the remaining distance to move based on the square magnitude of the difference between currente position and end parameter.
    //Square magnitude is used instead of magnitude because it's computationally cheaper.
    float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;
}

//While that distance is greater than a very small amount (Epsilon, almost zero):
while(sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon)
{
    //Find a new position proportionally closer to the end, based on the moveTime
    Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb2d.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime);

    //Call MovePosition on attached Rigidbody2D and move it to the calculated position.
    rb2d.MovePosition (newPosition);

    //Recalculate the remaining distance after moving.
    sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

    //Return and loop until sqrRemainingDistance is close enough to zero to end the function
    yield return null;
}
```

- Caso facilite para compreensão da pergunta, esse código foi fornecido
  pela unity e pode ser baixado [aqui](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/2d-roguelike-29825).
- Caso não seja possível ou seja inviável alterar o código fornecido, também aceito em um código isolado do game, já que meu objetivo é entender essa mecânica.

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função OnCollisionEnter para checar se houve colisão. Com o ´do while´ você faz o objeto se mover até que seja detectada a colisão. Dê uma olhada aqui: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html